# Terminated App on IOS 7 and Multitasking

Tags: ios, twitter, ios7, multitasking

is it possible to have the App Connection to a server Open even if the App has been Terminated from the Background ?

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish

Twitter Client should keep watching user events . and when that events occur it send a Local notification to the user . the whole idea is to stay a way from Push notification and all servers Problems and costs

so in order to to get Local notification works just like Push notification the connection between my IOS 7 App and Twitter API must be Open all the time

any idea if that even possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. What you're basically asking for is a *daemon* functionality which is not available on iOS. The whole point about iOS multitasking is that the OS can (and will) *terminate* your app if it is in the background and other tasks need the resources. That's the problem Push Notifications solve (to some degree).

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try background fetch feature on iOS 7 to periodically download content updates for user in background.